# Drawing gradient over image in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, gradient, layer

How to create gradient colour look like following image programatically.

[image]

Comment: You can use GPUIImage library from Brad Larson, it is well documented and really powerful.
It also has a lot of feature on images: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Comment: I need to apply it over the image as gradient..

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: if using GPUImage, which filter should I use to implement the gradient?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When you say "apply it over the image as a gradient", do you mean as a mask (revealing the image at the top, having it fade the image to transparent at the bottom)? If that's the case, you can apply that gradient as a mask, using `CAGradientLayer`:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradientMask = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientMask.frame = self.imageView.bounds;
gradientMask.colors = @[(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor,
                        (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
self.imageView.layer.mask = gradientMask;
```

---

The above does a simple vertical gradient (because the default is vertical, linear gradient). But you asked about `startPoint`, `endPoint`, and `locations`. If for example, you wanted your mask applied horizontally, you would do:

```
gradientMask.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);   // start at left middle
gradientMask.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);     // end at right middle
```

If you wanted to have two gradients, one at the first 10% and another at the last 10%, you'd do:

```
gradientMask.colors = @[(id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor,
                        (id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor,
                        (id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor,
                        (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
gradientMask.locations = @[@0.0, @0.10, @0.90, @1.0];
```

---

If you want a simple gradient by itself (not as a mask), you'd create a `view` and then add the gradient layer to it:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = view.bounds;
gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor,
                    (id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[view.layer addSublayer:gradient];
```

See the `CAGradientLayer` [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: thanks for help,bur i'm unable to understand start point,end point and locations of colors.

Comment: @user2823044 I've updated my example with illustration of `startPoint`, `endPoint`, and `locations`. You don't need them given your example of a vertical gradient, but if you wanted the gradient going from left to right, you could use `startPoint` and `endPoint`. If you wanted gradient to not be evenly spaced across that range of `startPoint` and `endPoint`, you could use `locations` (which you'd only really play around with if you had more than two `colors`).

Comment: how can i draw the gradient with single color(black) with decreasing alphs from bottom to top

Comment: @user2823044 See last example in my answer (no `startPoint`, `endPoint` or `locations` needed), but rather than going from `whiteColor` to `blackColor`, go from `blackColor` to `clearColor`.

Comment: Rob, I have a doubt adding a layer will affect memory or adding image as gradient is better.which has affect on memory leakage

Comment: @user2823044 Well, neither "leaks". If you're worried about memory consumption, though, adding a gradient image takes more memory than a `CAGradientLayer` (and more memory than a custom `drawRect` method with Core Graphics gradient calls, too). When you load an image, don't be mislead by the small size of the PNG/JPEG file, but rather when loaded into memory, it will generally take 4 bytes per pixel (e.g. a full screen retina resolution image for 4" iPhone will take 3mb; for retina iPad that jumps to 12mb).

Answer (score 7):

I just wrote an UIImage extension for Swift 2.0. Maybe it's of some use. You call it with an array of UIColor (any number) and a frame where the gradient should be drawn.

```
extension UIImage {

    class func convertGradientToImage(colors: [UIColor], frame: CGRect) -> UIImage {

        // start with a CAGradientLayer
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = frame

        // add colors as CGCologRef to a new array and calculate the distances
        var colorsRef = [CGColor]()
        var locations = [NSNumber]()

        for i in 0 ... colors.count-1 {
            colorsRef.append(colors[i].CGColor as CGColorRef)
            locations.append(Float(i)/Float(colors.count-1))
        }

        gradientLayer.colors = colorsRef
        gradientLayer.locations = locations

        // now build a UIImage from the gradient
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size)
        gradientLayer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        // return the gradient image
        return gradientImage
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
let colors = [
    UIColor.blueColor(),
    UIColor.greenColor()
    // and many more if you wish
]
let gradientImage = UIImage.convertGradientToImage(colors, frame: navigationBar.bounds)
```

and apply with:

```
.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: gradientImage)
```

or

```
.setBackgroundImage(gradientImage, forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

Comment: You beautiful, beautiful man/woman/child! I had a core graphics gradient rendering setup that worked for 99% of images that I was trying to draw a gradient on top of but there was always that 1% that failed to draw the image and ended up butchering the quality of the image, making it all corrupted/grainy/pixelated. With the gradient layer it works perfectly everywhere (or so it seems). Bloody Apple...

Answer (score 2):

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;


gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0); //Dark From bottom
gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0);


gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   (id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor],
                   (id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor], nil];


[self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best approach, working for me as requirement

```
CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientLayer.frame = yourImageView.layer.bounds;

gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor,
                        (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.9f].CGColor,
                        nil];

gradientLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f],
                           nil];

[yourImageView.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) drawGradientinBounds: (CGRect) currentBounds withColors:(NSArray*) colors andPercentages:(NSArray *)percentages andGradientDirectionIsVertical:(BOOL)isGradientDirectionVertical
{

    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGGradientRef glossGradient;
    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorspace;

    size_t num_locations = [percentages count];
    CGFloat locations[num_locations];
    for(int i=0;i<num_locations;i++)
        locations[i] = [[percentages objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];

    int comps = [colors count]*4;
    CGFloat components[comps];
    for(int i = [colors count]-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        comps--;
        UIColor *c = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
        const CGFloat *cg = CGColorGetComponents([c CGColor]);
        components[comps] = cg[3];
        comps--;
        components[comps] = cg[2];
        comps--;
        components[comps] = cg[1];
        comps--;
        components[comps] = cg[0];
    }

    rgbColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    glossGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgbColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);

    CGPoint topCenter;
    CGPoint endCenter;

    if(isGradientDirectionVertical)
    {
        topCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds), currentBounds.origin.y);
        endCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds), CGRectGetHeight(currentBounds)+currentBounds.origin.y);

    }
    else
    {
        topCenter = CGPointMake( currentBounds.origin.x,CGRectGetMidY(currentBounds));
        endCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(currentBounds)+currentBounds.origin.x,CGRectGetMidY(currentBounds));
    }
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(currentContext, glossGradient, topCenter, endCenter, 0);

    CGGradientRelease(glossGradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorspace);
}
```

And the input to this method are bounds, colorArray:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor blackColor], [UIColor whiteColor], nil]
```

percentageArray:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil]
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 adaptation of RyuX51 answer.

```swift
extension UIImage {

    static func convertGradientToImage(colors: [UIColor], frame: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
        /// start with a `CAGradientLayer`
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = frame

        /// add colors as `CGColor` to a new array and calculate the distances
        var colorsRef = [CGColor]()
        var locations = [NSNumber]()

        for i in .zero ... colors.count - 1 {
            colorsRef.append(colors[i].cgColor as CGColor)
            locations.append(NSNumber(value: (Float(i) / Float(colors.count - 1))))
        }

        gradientLayer.colors = colorsRef
        gradientLayer.locations = locations

        /// now build a `UIImage` from the gradient
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size)

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return nil
        }

        gradientLayer.render(in: context)

        let gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        /// return the gradient image
        return gradientImage
    }
}
```

Comment: You should at least give credit to the other answer that you made minor syntax changes to.

Comment: At least? At what would be not at least? I guess you want too much, why not just say "thank you" for my time I spent making the answer compilable?

Comment: Sorry, but when you post someone else's work as your own, it's called plagiarism. Just because you spent 5 minutes fixing a few lines to make it compile with a newer version of Swift doesn't mean you shouldn't give credit to the original author of the code.