# Objective-C apply css style for UiImageView

Tags: css, objective-c, uiimageview

Hello i have the imageview

[image]

The css i got from boss is :
/* Rectangle 3: */
background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, rgba(137,129,129,0.00) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.51) 100%);

I search many websites but it's seem impossible.
I read that post [Drawing gradient over image in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22810839/drawing-gradient-over-image-in-ios) then i think is that a solution to apply that css to my image. Or convert this css to objective C code.

Does someone meet same problem?

Answer (score 0):

For this case, you can use gradient color as you already told. The trick is, put gradient color to a view and place that view over image view, and than set its opacity (alpha) to 0.51f.

You check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23074670/5513229) for a `CAGradientLayer` example and another option is using a great color library [Chameleon](https://github.com/ViccAlexander/Chameleon) for creating gradient color and layer.